# How can I apply a formula to new, form-inserted rows of data in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I would like my Google spreadsheet to automatically apply formulas found in cells F2 to H2 to all new, form-inserted rows. [You can view the spreadsheet here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtEC1r7s57ipdHJvdER6TGFQRXR3eE5WS2dtMFUzb0E&usp=sharing)

The formulas are:

F2: **=IF(B2, "I"&B2,"--")**

G2: **=vlookup(C2,SectionID!$A$2:$B$13,2,FALSE)**

H2: **=vlookup(D2,ReporterID!$A$2:$B$12,2, FALSE)**

I have tried manually applying the formulas to rows 3 to 10, but when a form is submitted, the data is added to newly created rows which do not contain the formulas. (Form data is submitted to columns A to E.)

Feel free to make changes to the spreadsheet.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to either use a script to populate the formulae on form submission, or use the out-of-the-box solution which is an array formula:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A;IF(B2:B;"I"&B2:B;"--");IFERROR(1/0)))`

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C;SectionID!$A$2:$B$13;2*SIGN(ROW(A2:A));FALSE)))`

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D;ReporterID!$A$2:$B$12;2*SIGN(ROW(A2:A));FALSE)))`

[Here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/docs/parallel$20lookup$20solution/docs/36A0epDlIdE/qnywZst0DioJ) is a bit of discussion about the trick involved in converting VLOOKUP to iterate down an array.

You can also invoke formulae in row 1 to populate the headers as well, which mitigates against the scenario where a row might be inserted above row 2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A:A)=1;"IssueID";IF(A:A;IF(B:B;"I"&B:B;"--");IFERROR(1/0))))`

`=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A:A)=1;"SectionID";IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C:C;SectionID!$A$2:$B$13;2*SIGN(ROW(A:A));FALSE))))`

`=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A:A)=1;"ReporterID";IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D:D;ReporterID!$A$2:$B$12;2*SIGN(ROW(A:A));FALSE))))`

Comment: This worked perfectly. I've set the spreadsheet to view only so that your solution isn't changed in any way. Thank you for your time.